# Order of growth as worst case running time as a function of N

Tags: algorithm, performance

Given the following code fragment:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i*i; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j*j; k++)
            sum++;
```

My assumption:

- Outer loop: O(N)
- Middle loop: O(N*N)
- Innermost loop: O(N*N)

Hence, total running time should be O(N^5), right?

Comment: Isn't most inner loop O (N^2 * N^2)?

Comment: Damn, the answer is : N^7

For a given value of i, the body of the innermost loop is executed 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + (i^2)^2 ~ 1/3 i^6 times. Summing up over all values of i yields ~ 1/21 N^7.

Comment: You are right. Complexity will be O(n^5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A preliminary remark**

```
sum(k=1,p,k^2) = p(p+1)(2p+1)/6 = O(p^3)
sum(k=1,p,k^6) = O(p^7)
```

**Computation of complexity**

1. The most inner loop runs from `k=1` to `j^2` so it does exactly `j^2` operations.
2. The middle loop runs from `j=1` to `i^2` and at each step we do `j^2` operations. According to my preliminary observation, by substituting `p=i^2` in the first equation, we can compute the total operations as: `i^2(i^2+1)(2*i^2+1)/6` for each value of `i`. This is an `O((i^2)^3) = O(i^6)` number of operations.
3. The outer loop runs from `i=1` to `n` and does `O(i^6)` operations at each step. So we have `O(n^7)` operations.

**References**

- http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/power.htm

Comment: Seems, that is the correct way to solve the problems like these. Also, I don't know if SO has some Latex kind of syntax, it would have been much easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 1):

Lets open up how many times every loop will run.

```
First loop    1, 2,   3,   4,   5,  ...., N
Second loop   1, 4,   9,  16,  25, ...., (N*N)             // N^2
Third loop    1, 16, 81, 256, 625, ...., ( (N*N)*(N*N) )   // N^4
```

So, i think the complexity should be N^4

**EDIT 1**

Based on a comment, i think the complexity will be sum of the series

```
1, 16, 81, 256, 625, ...., ( (N*N)*(N*N) )
```

**EDIT 2**

I think we made a mistake in opening the loops (Thanks to [CodeYogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4260745/codeyogi)). Lets try one more time.

```
First loop    1, 2,   3,   4,   5,  ...., N
Second loop   1,  4(1,2,3, 4), 9  (1,2,....9),  16,  25, ...., (N*N)  
Third loop    1, 30(1+4+9+16), 285(1+4+...81), and so on..........
```

Comment: I think the running time should be the sum of the series `1 + 16 + 81 ... + (N*N) * (N*N)`, wdyt?

Comment: by analogy `1 + 2 + 3 ~ O(N^2)`, `1 + 4 + 9 ~ O(N^3)`, hence above solution should be O(N^5), right?

Comment: Complexity is O(n^5). I don't know how your wrong answer got 3 upvotes on this (because you say that complexity is O(n^4)

Comment: @haris, I think we are wrong and there is a serious wrong in our thinking. It should be ~O(N^7)

Comment: see fjardon's answer above. I have checked that its the most accurate way to solve problems like these, i.e. nested integration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the final O is definitely higher then `O(n^4)` and slightly higher then `O(n^5)`, but since this is Big O notation, we can say that it is **O(n^5)**. Last loop will execute this amount of times:

```
1 + 2^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 + ... + n^4
```

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2B%202%5E4%20%2B%203%5E4%20%2B%204%5E4%20%2B%20...%20%2B%20n%5E4) represents it as:

[image]

Please note expanded version for `n>0`:

[image]

**Edit:**

I just realized, that there is a gap in my answer, cause most inner loop will be executed more times than I assumed. Looking at results of this triple loop and plotting it, it seems it is higher than`O(n^6)`. Will get back to it.

**Edit 2:**
As I mentioned, I was wrong. Cannot explain it better than @fjardon in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470971/order-of-growth-as-worst-case-running-time-as-a-function-of-n).